# How to show more results for our brand name when searched for in Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, social-media, branding, wikipedia

**The question,** TL;DR:

SERP is filled with a lot of comparison and review websites. **How do I show my own subdomains, Twitter feed, and Wikipedia entry when a user searches for my "brand"**?

Slightly longer version:

The company I work for has got a decent brand reputation. We have a Wikipedia page, regularly updated social media feed and several useful subdomains. However, when someone searches for "company name", a couple of our subdomains are getting grouped in the sitelinks.

Now, when you search for our competitor brands (slightly higher brand reputation than us, but not 2x) you can see their Twitter feed under the sitelinks. The subdomains are not getting grouped in the sitelinks and there's a list of their similar subdomains below the Twitter feed. Their Wikipedia page appears below that and comparison and review websites are nowhere to be found.

Basically, I want more of our brand results to show in the SERP when someone searches for our brand name. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few thing you can do to get more visibility on brand searches.

#### Sitelinks

If you want Google to show more [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) on your brand search you should try the following:

- Submit an updated XML sitemap
- Use internal links with accurate anchors
- Link only relevant categories in the menu
- Make sure your page load is good (they will be able to check more pages)
- Check Search Console terms that drive traffic to your site. Understand what your visitors are looking for and make sure you have a browsing directory up to it.
- Avoid HTML/JS errors on the site

#### Subdomains

Make sure all your subdomains are using the brand on titles and content and they have enough popularity to rank. They must have a good internal linking between them and the main site.

#### Extra brand domain

You can use a brand-domain (for example somethingmybrand.com). You should use it only for a specific content and it will rank easily in TOP10. For example: savemoneywithbrand.com, learntoflywithbrand.com, etc.

#### Linking press site

There is no need for all TOP10 results to be of your own. You can link pages that mentions your brand and talk good about it. For example, you can have: example.com/press and there you can include updated links to the sites that are talking and linking to your web.

#### Adwords

Doing brand PPC-campaings will help you getting more visibility on TOP10. It's cheap and you can even [use sitelinks](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375416?hl=en).

#### Competitors

Analyze your main competitors TOP20 brand results. I'm aware you already did that, but make sure you know exactly what public profiles they have and how they are linked.

Answer (score 1):

When someone searches for your brand, I'm guessing you want the SERP results to look like:

1. brand.com
2. wikipedia.org/brand
3. twitter.com/brand
4. facebook.com/brand
5. youtube.com/brand
6. instagram.com/brand

If you want all of those websites to rank from your company, then you are probably going to have to grow on all of those sites. For instance, if you have a somewhat dead twitter profile without much action, Google may choose not to rank that in their results. The more followers, retweets, posts and action you have on the twitter, instagram, facebook and youtube sites, the more likely it is that Google will rank those. I recommend that you grow them as big as you can.

You should also be linking to your social media profiles from your company website if you haven't done so already, and any other websites that you want to rank for your brand. If your website links to your twitter account, Google will see this as a ranking signal that your twitter profile should be ranking for your brand search.

As for why your subdomains are showing up in site links and not as their own entity I'm not entirely sure. But the more links you have pointing to those subdomains and the better the content is on those subdomains the more likely it will be that Google makes them their own ranking entries.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site#add-your-sites-name-logo-and-social-links

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile

Check these above links-
and also make sure that-

You are using schema markup for your social media profiles on your site as well as for your search box.
also for your address on your site.

for twitter  make sure
your twitter username and handle same as your business name.
updating your twitter several times a day...
use your business keywords on your twitter
your social accounts are on your Wikipedia page.

Get Google knowledge graph and use Google business listing for your help.

Just complete all these tasks you will get your twitter feed, knowledge graph, sitelinks search and other Google SERP features...

But the final decision is in Google's hand and depends upon your traffic and brand value.